# Is there a built-in Java method to box an array?

Tags: java, boxing

Is there a standard method I can use in place of this custom method?

```
public static Byte[] box(byte[] byteArray) {
    Byte[] box = new Byte[byteArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        box[i] = byteArray[i];
    }
    return box;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to create an array of boxed values?

Comment: Probably to use them in a list or another data structure, because java does not permit primitive generics.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, there is no such method in the JDK.

As it's often the case, however, [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) provides [such a method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject(byte[])).

Answer (score 25):

Enter Java 8, and you can do following (boxing):

```
int [] ints = ...
Integer[] boxedInts = IntStream.of(ints).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

However, this only works for `int[]`, `long[]`, and `double[]`. This will not work for `byte[]`.

You can also easily accomplish the reverse (unboxing)

```
Integer [] boxedInts = ...
int [] ints = Stream.of(boxedInts).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: you can also: `List<Integer> boxedList = IntStream.of(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @juanmf correct, but that does not answer the post directly: a `List<Integer>` is not an `Integer []` as is requested for a boxed _array_.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to YoYo's answer, you can do this for *any* primitive type; let `primArray` be an identifier of type `PrimType[]`, then you *can* do the following:

```
BoxedType[] boxedArray = IntStream.range(0, primArray.length).mapToObj(i -> primArray[i]).toArray(BoxedType[] :: new);
```

Comment: I have seen this solution several times - and in my guts it does not seem like a clean solution (the way you bring in a non-enclosed variable). However I do not seem to find a real good argument against it.

Answer (score 1):

When looking into Apache Commons Lang source code, we can see that it just calls `Byte#valueOf(byte)` on each array element.

```
    final Byte[] result = new Byte[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result[i] = Byte.valueOf(array[i]);
    }
    return result;
```

Meanwhile, regular java lint tools suggest that boxing is unnecessary and you can just assign elements as is.

So essentially you're doing the same thing apache commons does.