# Java: byte[1] vs byte[1024]

Tags: java, byte

I've been trying to get some streams working via TCP however I seem to fail, probably due to the fact that I don't understand byte streams enough.

I know what a byte it, it's 8-bit. example: 0000 0001 (which would be "int 1")

When i define let's say:

```
Byte[] myByte = new byte[1];
```

What does the "1" do? Is myByte capable of carrying only one byte?

Comment: Are you asking what an array is? Because the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) tutorial is pretty clear what the `1` is.

Comment: You are just making an array with `byte[] myByte = new byte[1];` part of the code.

Comment: Nono I know very well what an Array is, so your saying that the number defines how many bytes the byte[] may carry?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ah alright, I was looking at Byte tutorials, not the Array one, think you just answered my question :)

Answer (score 2):

`new type[x]` is the syntax for an expression creating an *array [object]* (of type `type[]`<sup>1</sup>) with `x` elements.

See the [Nuts & Bolts: Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. *The length of an array is established when the array [object] is created* (i.e. `new byte[1]`). After creation, its length is fixed ..

So, `new byte[1]` creates an array [object] for a single byte (length = 1), and `new byte[1024]` creates an array of 1024 byte elements (length = 1024).

---

<sup>1</sup> The code in the post is a bit "funny" because it uses `Byte[]` as the array type but `new byte[1]` to create the actual array object; it should be `byte` in both places. I'm ignoring that as a typo because automatic boxing of a primitive array is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585907/is-there-a-build-in-java-method-to-box-an-array) in Java.