# Java float[] to Float[] one-line conversion

Tags: java, type-conversion

I am trying to convert float array into Float array.

I know how to do it with for() loop, but I am searching for a single-line solution if there is one.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30635884/19018243) for int[] to Integer[], but could not find a way for the floats. One of the  mentioned solution in that post looks like this (as I said it is for int[] to Integer[])

```
int [] ints = ...
Integer[] boxedInts = IntStream.of(ints).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

What I am asking is: is there a modification to above line so that it would apply to floats regarding my question, please?

Comment: fozzybear's answer is probably closest to what you are looking for.

Comment: This is a pretty simple and straight forward solution: `Float[] array = IntStream.range(0, floats.length).mapToObj(i -> floats[i]).toArray(Float[]::new);
`

Comment: @ODDminus1 your answer is the correct one - if you'd make normal post out of it I would select it as the solution. - thank you for help

Comment: @Sweeper who/where is fozzybear? I do not see his answer here.

Comment: Their answer is in the duplicate target. It's basically the same as what ODDminus1 suggested.

Comment: It might be somewhere in the duplicate target, but the target was very large and broad while this question was concise. Since the question is marked as a duplicate, answers are not allowed, so the comment will be all.

Comment: @ODDminus1 aha, OK - got that, thank you for explanation. I at least flagged your answer as being useful, if nothing more.