# Integer - Cannot pass int[] in an Integer[] method

Tags: java, arrays, generics, integer

I am trying to take a few steps back and work on some simple math functions like vectors just for fun (So technically I'm not in search of any library). I wanted to add a feature where you can pass an array of 3 number in order to set the values.

```
public class Vector3 <T> extends Vectors {
    
    private T x;
    private T y;
    private T z;
    
    Vector3() {}
    
    public Vector3<T> set(T x, T y, T z) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.z=z;
        
        return this;
    }

    public Vector3<T> set(T[] arr) {
        
        if(arr.length > 3) throw new InvalidParameterException("Cannot use array with length greater than 3");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(i == 0) x = arr[i];
            else if(i == 1) y = arr[i];
            else if(i == 2) z = arr[i];
        }
        
        return this;
    }
    
    public T getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public T getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public T getZ() {
        return z;
    }
}
```

Well, this code allows the class to be easily implemented using `Vector3<Integer> vec = new Vector3<Integer>()`. So, the issue with the set method is I have to use an array of the `Integer` class instead of the primitive `int`. Is it possible for me to just use an array of normal int?

Comment: Not generically. `int[]` and `Integer[]` are unrelated types.

Comment: Generic type T can't represent primitive type which means that `T[]` can't represent `int[]`.

Comment: "But I can pass an int or a number directly to a method that takes in an Integer" that is because of autoboxing which works for converting primitive types and its object representations like `int` and `Integer`. BUT there is no autoboxing for arrays (even of primitive type).

Comment: Out of interest, what would be the point in using anything other than the largest possible floating point type? Why genericize?

Comment: So there is technically no actual way to fix this issue?

Comment: @g00se really depends on what the user wants, he wants a double he can easily return a double, I do not have an exact reason but it would be cool (at least for me) to implement it ;)

Comment: And yes I do understand the fact that they could just cast it to a different type but it really doesn't hurt to implement it :)

Comment: As the int->Integer conversion is called (auto-)boxing, this may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585907/is-there-a-built-in-java-method-to-box-an-array

Comment: I want to pass the values directly. Well, I could make methods, but I mentioned in my question that I'm using generics, all the methods and values use the type (which extends number btw). If I made methods it would require me to make one for all types (because I want this thing to return the type they wont and they dont have to cast it to anything) and it would go all crazy.

Comment: That's all well and good, but so far there are no methods of any substance. As soon as you add some which concern calculation, then you'll probably find type checking is required. Try it!

Comment: "*using generics*" ==> no primitives

Comment: Sure @g00se thanks!

Comment: @AlsoGrindingForReputation, you should find no deviation in using an _Integer_ _array_, over an _int_ _array_.

Comment: @Reilas having to use `Integer.valueOf()` is quite annoying to type but ig it dont matter :shrug:

Answer (score -1):

In Java, you cannot use primitive types (like int, float, etc.) as generic type arguments, including in your Vector3 class. Generic types in Java must be reference types, so you will have to use their corresponding wrapper classes (e.g., Integer for int) when defining the generic type.

However, you can still work with primitive int values by overloading the set method to accept an array of int and then use autoboxing to convert them into the corresponding Integer objects.

```
public class Vector3<T> {

    private T x;
    private T y;
    private T z;

    Vector3() {}

    public Vector3<T> set(T x, T y, T z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;

        return this;
    }

    public Vector3<T> set(T[] arr) {

        if (arr.length != 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array must have exactly 3 elements");
        }

        this.x = arr[0];
        this.y = arr[1];
        this.z = arr[2];

        return this;
    }

    public Vector3<T> set(int[] arr) {

        if (arr.length != 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array must have exactly 3 elements");
        }

        this.x = (T) Integer.valueOf(arr[0]);
        this.y = (T) Integer.valueOf(arr[1]);
        this.z = (T) Integer.valueOf(arr[2]);

        return this;
    }

    public T getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public T getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public T getZ() {
        return z;
    }
}
```

I added an overloaded set method that accepts an array of int. Inside this method, I use autoboxing to convert the int values into Integer objects before assigning them to x, y, and z. This way, you can use both arrays of Integer and arrays of int to set the values of your Vector3 object.